# PHP shell_exec not working perfectly

Tags: php, exec, system, shell-exec

I add user with right permission in this file:

```
/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
```

But `shell_exec,system,exec` can't run all command. For example I can go to root folder and get list of files and directory in `/root` folder, but when i use

```
shell_exec('ffmpeg');
```

nothing execute and nothing reply.
What should i do?

Comment: try executing 'ls' . do you get anything?

Comment: `ffmpeg` needs a filename argument. What do you expect it to do with no argument?

Comment: `shell_exec()` returns the output of the command. If you want to see it, you need to echo it with `echo shell_exec('ffmpeg')`. If you also want to see error messages, you should redirect stderr, `echo shell_exec('ffmpeg 2>&1');`

Comment: ls,cd /root and other command work very well and return output but when i use shell_exec('fmpeg ...') return is empty but when i type this command in linux terminal convert my file perfectly.

Comment: @barmar the result of `shell_exec('ffmpeg 2>&1');` is   `sh: ffmpeg: command not found `

Comment: Use the full path of the command, since it's not installed in the default search path.

Comment: @barmar thanks ,solved.how can run ffmpeg in anywhere?